# How to make reducers reusable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have 2 apps inside my CRA that use the same UI but do slightly different things. at the moment I am using lots of similar reducers for the 2 apps and am wondering the best way to make them reusable and not duplicate the code?

app1:

```
export default (state: App1State = initialState, action: ReducerAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case APP_1.ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                id: 123,
                app1SpecificState: 'app1'
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

app2:

```
export default (state: App2State = initialState, action: ReducerAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case APP_2.ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                id: 123,
                app2SpecificState: 'app1'
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

so to combine them I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
export default (state: App1State = initialState, action: ReducerAction) => {
if (process.env.APP_NAME === 'app2') {
    (state as App2State) = App2State
}
    switch (action.type) {
        case APP_1.ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                id: 123,
                app1SpecificState: 'app1'
         }
        case APP_2.ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                id: 123,
                app2SpecificState: 'app2'
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if a) this makes sense b) this is a good idea c) there is a better way to achieve this?

I also don't want to repeat the if statement across all my "shared" reducers so would be good to abstract this if possible. probably a HOC, if that's even possible here?

Comment: are the urls different in the 2 apps?  You could use a url path as an identifier for each app and then you could resove `app1` or `app2` from there.

Comment: how would that be different from an env var though? it would still be conditional logic to determine which actions to fire, no?

Comment: @DavinTryon see above

Answer (score 0):

The redux documentation has recipes for that, check it out:

[Reusing reducer logic](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic)

If you need to create new parts of redux store dynamically, you can also add more reducers later:

[Add reducer dynamically](https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting#reducer-injection-approaches)

Comment: ok the docs look ok, but they don't suggest anything about conditional state which is something I might have. or rather changing initial state

Comment: What kind of conditional state?

Comment: as in, for my app1 I need a certain state object as initial state, for my app2 I need a different certain state object, so depending on what app loads I need to start with different initial states but ultimately using the same reducer...if that makes sense?

Comment: If you want just different initial state objects, you can define initial state as empty and dispatch new action INIT_STATE with different (initial) data in both apps/components once.

Comment: but it's different initial state for each reducer. there must be an easy way to pass it in when i initiated the reducer?

Comment: I understand that the initial state is different. I suggested that you have it empty in the both 'instances' of reducer. And init their state by your components. Your `componentA` would once (e.g. in `componentDidMount`) dispatch action `{type: INIT_STATE, payload: dataA}` and `componentB` would dispatch action `{type: INIT_STATE, payload: dataB}`

Answer (score 0):

In order to update your store dynamically you should dispatch your data with its property name like this:

```
dispatch({
    type: APP.ACTION,
    payload: "app1",
    specificState: "app1SpecificState"
})
dispatch({
    type: APP.ACTION,
    payload: "app2",
    specificState: "app2SpecificState"
})
```

and then in your reducer you can use like this:

```
case APP.ACTION:
        return {
            ...state,
            id: 123,
            [action.specificState]: action.payload
     }
```

It is the same principle as updating the state dynamically.